# TypeError: a.onload is not a function

Tags: javascript

After I read Image, I want to use canvas's drawImage.

but id does not work.
when I call onload,

```
TypeError: a.onload is not a function
```

it happened.

what's wrong?

```
let ctx = new Image();
　ctx.onload(() => {　
　this.compositedImage.drawImage(ctx, 0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height, 0, 0,　is.compositedCanvas.width, this.compositedCanvas.height);
　resolver(this);
}, this);
```

it is written in a Promise context, so is it related to this?

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.onload = () => {}` or better use `addEventListener` like this `ctx.addEventListener('load', () => {})`

Comment: I tried below, but the same error happened ...                                   

ctx.onload = () => {}

Comment: Assuming this was the only call to `onload` as a function in your code snippet there is no way to get same error. The original problem should be fixed as I have described. If you want any further help please create [mcve] demonstrating the issue.